# Adding classes to content_tag in Rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I want to add a class to the `(:i)` tag inside the Rails code:

```
<td><%= link_to content_tag(:i), item %></td>
```

I want the final code to look like:

```
<td><a href="/items/2"><i class="#"></i></a></td>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

@Dogbert is correct, except that you need to pass `nil` as the second parameter, since `content_tag` is defined as

```
def content_tag(tag, content_or_options_with_block=nil, options=nil, escape=true, &block)
  ...
end
```

The second parameter is only considered content if you pass block. To expand on it, any extra options passed in at that point will become HTML attributes, so the same form applies to things like IDs, data-*, etc.

```
content_tag(:i, nil, class: '#', id: 'foo', data: {foo: 'bar'})
```

will become

```
<i class="#" id="foo" data-foo="bar"></i>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

<%= link_to content_tag(:i, :class => '#'), item %>